# Cannot import JIRA REST API wadl into Postman

Tags: postman, jira-rest-api, wadl

I unsuccessfully try to import the JIRA API information from the following URI in wadl-format into Postman.

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/jira-rest-plugin.wadl

No matter if I try directly via URI, download and use the file or copy/paste the raw text, Postman complains about the format.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Greetings,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Today, I stumbled over the exact same issue as you :-)
I could finally import the wadl into soapui by just removing a couple of lines from the wadl file.

```
diff jira-rest-plugin*
861,868c861
<                 path="api/2/priority"><ns2:method id="getPriorities"
<                     name="GET"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returns a list of all issue priorities.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:response
<                         status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a list of Jira Priorities]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                         element="list of priorities"
<                                 mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                 xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>[{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/priority/3","statusColor":"#009900","description":"Major loss of function.","iconUrl":"http://www.example.com/jira/images/icons/priorities/major.png","name":"Major"},{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/priority/5","statusColor":"#cfcfcf","description":"Very little impact.","iconUrl":"http://www.example.com/jira/images/icons/priorities/trivial.png","name":"Trivial"}]</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returned if the priorities exists and the user has permission to view it. Contains a full representation of
<  the priority in JSON format.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                 xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/list-of-priority#","title":"List of Priority","type":"array","items":{"title":"Priority","type":"object","properties":{"self":{"type":"string"},"statusColor":{"type":"string"},"description":{"type":"string"},"iconUrl":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false}}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response></ns2:method><ns2:resource
---
>                 path="api/2/priority"><ns2:resource
939,944c932
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[an issue counts bean]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="issue Count Bean"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/component/10000","issueCount":23}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returned if the component exists and the currently authenticated user has permission to view it. Contains
<  counts of issues related to this component.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/component-issue-counts#","title":"Component Issue Counts","type":"object","properties":{"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"},"issueCount":{"type":"integer"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["issueCount"]}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[an issue counts bean]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
1131,1136c1119
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[an issue counts bean]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="issue Count Bean"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/version/10000","issuesFixedCount":23,"issuesAffectedCount":101,"issueCountWithCustomFieldsShowingVersion":54,"customFieldUsage":[{"fieldName":"Field1","customFieldId":10000,"issueCountWithVersionInCustomField":2},{"fieldName":"Field2","customFieldId":10010,"issueCountWithVersionInCustomField":3}]}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returned if the version exists and the currently authenticated user has permission to view it. Contains
<  counts of issues fixed in and affecting this version, custom fields connected to this version.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/version-issue-counts#","title":"Version Issue Counts","type":"object","properties":{"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"},"issuesFixedCount":{"type":"integer"},"issuesAffectedCount":{"type":"integer"},"issueCountWithCustomFieldsShowingVersion":{"type":"integer"},"customFieldUsage":{"type":"array","items":{"title":"Version Usage In Custom Fields","type":"object","properties":{"fieldName":{"type":"string"},"customFieldId":{"type":"integer"},"issueCountWithVersionInCustomField":{"type":"integer"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["customFieldId","issueCountWithVersionInCustomField"]}}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["issuesFixedCount","issuesAffectedCount","issueCountWithCustomFieldsShowingVersion"]}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[an issue counts bean]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
1684,1688c1667
<                         status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a response containing all fields as short Field Meta Beans]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                         element="List of field"
<                                 mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                 xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>[{"id":"description","name":"Description","custom":false,"orderable":true,"navigable":true,"searchable":true,"clauseNames":["description"],"schema":{"type":"string","system":"description"}},{"id":"summary","key":"summary","name":"Summary","custom":false,"orderable":true,"navigable":true,"searchable":true,"clauseNames":["summary"],"schema":{"type":"string","system":"summary"}}]</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Contains a full representation of all visible fields in JSON.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<             xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/list-of-field#","title":"List of Field","type":"array","items":{"title":"Field","type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"string"},"key":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"custom":{"type":"boolean"},"orderable":{"type":"boolean"},"navigable":{"type":"boolean"},"searchable":{"type":"boolean"},"clauseNames":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"}},"schema":{"title":"Json Type","type":"object","properties":{"type":{"type":"string"},"items":{"type":"string"},"system":{"type":"string"},"custom":{"type":"string"},"customId":{"type":"integer"}},"additionalProperties":false}},"additionalProperties":false}}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response></ns2:method></ns2:resource><ns2:resource
---
>                         status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a response containing all fields as short Field Meta Beans]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response></ns2:method></ns2:resource><ns2:resource
1759,1763c1738
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a response containing newly created tab]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="Newly created tab"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":10000,"name":"Fields Tab"}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Newly created tab in JSON.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/screenable-tab#","title":"Screenable Tab","type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"},"name":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a response containing newly created tab]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
1775,1779c1750
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a response containing renamed tab]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="Modified tab"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":10000,"name":"Fields Tab"}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Modified tab in JSON.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/screenable-tab#","title":"Screenable Tab","type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"},"name":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a response containing renamed tab]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
2169,2174c2140,2141
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[A response]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="raw attachment contents"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"entries":[{"entryIndex":0,"name":"Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3","size":1430174,"mediaType":"audio/mpeg"},{"entryIndex":1,"name":"lrm.rtf","size":331,"mediaType":"text/rtf"}],"totalEntryCount":24}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[JSON representation of the attachment expanded contents. Empty entry list means that attachment cannot
<  be expanded. It's either empty, corrupt or not an archive at all.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/attachment-archive-impl#","title":"Attachment Archive Impl","type":"object","properties":{"entries":{"type":"array","items":{"title":"Attachment Archive Entry","type":"object","properties":{"abbreviatedName":{"type":"string"},"entryIndex":{"type":"integer"},"mediaType":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"size":{"type":"integer"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["entryIndex","size"]}},"totalEntryCount":{"type":"integer"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["totalEntryCount"]}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[A response]]></ns2:doc>
>                           </ns2:response><ns2:response
2187,2192c2154
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[A response]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="human readable attachment contents"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":7237823,"name":"images.zip","entries":[{"path":"MG00N067.JPG","index":0,"size":"119 kB","mediaType":"image/jpeg","label":"MG00N067.JPG"},{"path":"Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3","index":1,"size":"1.36 MB","mediaType":"audio/mpeg","label":"Allegro from Duet in C Major.mp3"},{"path":"long/path/thanks/to/lots/of/subdirectories/inside/making/it/quite/hard/to/reach/the/leaf.txt","index":2,"size":"0.0 k","mediaType":"text/plain","label":"long/path/thanks/to/.../reach/the/leaf.txt"}],"totalEntryCount":39,"mediaType":"application/zip"}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[JSON representation of the attachment expanded contents. Empty entry list means that attachment cannot
<  be expanded. It's either empty, corrupt or not an archive at all.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/human-readable-archive#","title":"Human Readable Archive","type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"},"name":{"type":"string"},"entries":{"type":"array","items":{"title":"Human Readable Archive Entry","type":"object","properties":{"path":{"type":"string"},"index":{"type":"integer"},"size":{"type":"string"},"mediaType":{"type":"string"},"label":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["index"]}},"totalEntryCount":{"type":"integer"},"mediaType":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["id","totalEntryCount"]}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[A response]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
2283,2287c2245
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a response containing {@link com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.rest.json.beans.EntityPropertyBean}.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="dashboard item-property"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"key":"issue.support","value":{"hipchat.room.id":"support-123","support.time":"1m"}}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returned if the dashboard item property was found.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/entity-property#","title":"Entity Property","type":"object","properties":{"key":{"type":"string"},"value":{}},"additionalProperties":false}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a response containing {@link com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.rest.json.beans.EntityPropertyBean}.]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
2292,2297c2250
<                         status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a list of JIRA issue resolutions]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                         element="list of resolutions"
<                                 mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                 xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>[{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/resolution/1","description":"A fix for this issue is checked into the tree and tested.","iconUrl":"http://www.example.com/jira/images/icons/statuses/resolved.png","name":"Fixed"},{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/resolution/3","description":"This is what it is supposed to do.","name":"Works as designed"}]</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returned if the resolutions exists and the user has permission to view them. Contains a full representation of
<  the resolution in JSON format.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                 xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/list-of-resolution#","title":"List of Resolution","type":"array","items":{"title":"Resolution","type":"object","properties":{"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"},"description":{"type":"string"},"iconUrl":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false}}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response></ns2:method><ns2:resource
---
>                         status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a list of JIRA issue resolutions]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response></ns2:method><ns2:resource
2569,2573c2522
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[A list of user objects that match the username provided]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="List of users"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>[{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=fred","key":"fred","accountId":"99:27935d01-92a7-4687-8272-a9b8d3b2ae2e","name":"fred","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&amp;ownerId=fred","24x24":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;ownerId=fred","16x16":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&amp;ownerId=fred","32x32":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&amp;ownerId=fred"},"displayName":"Fred F. User","active":false},{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=andrew","key":"andrew","accountId":"99:e2a16dd9-2ffb-4a4b-a9bd-bd1145a020ee","name":"andrew","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&amp;ownerId=andrew","24x24":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;ownerId=andrew","16x16":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&amp;ownerId=andrew","32x32":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&amp;ownerId=andrew"},"displayName":"Andrew Anderson","active":false}]</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returns a full representation of a JIRA user in JSON format.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/list-of-user#","title":"List of User","type":"array","items":{"title":"User","type":"object","properties":{"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"},"key":{"type":"string"},"accountId":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"emailAddress":{"type":"string"},"avatarUrls":{"type":"object","patternProperties":{".+":{"type":"string","format":"uri"}},"additionalProperties":false},"displayName":{"type":"string"},"active":{"type":"boolean"},"timeZone":{"type":"string"},"locale":{"type":"string"},"groups":{"$ref":"#/definitions/simple-list-wrapper"},"applicationRoles":{"$ref":"#/definitions/simple-list-wrapper"},"expand":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["active"]},"definitions":{"simple-list-wrapper":{"title":"Simple List Wrapper","type":"object","properties":{"size":{"type":"integer"},"max-results":{"type":"integer"},"items":{"type":"array","items":{"title":"Group","type":"object","properties":{"name":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"}},"additionalProperties":false}}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["size"]}}}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[A list of user objects that match the username provided]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
2591,2595c2540
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[An object containing list of matched user objects, with html representing highlighting.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="List of users"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"users":[{"name":"fred","key":"fred","html":"fred@example.com","displayName":"Fred Grumble","avatarUrl":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;ownerId=fred"}],"total":25,"header":"Showing 20 of 25 matching groups"}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returns a full representation of a JIRA user in JSON format.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/user-picker-results#","title":"User Picker Results","type":"object","properties":{"users":{"type":"array","items":{"title":"User Picker User","type":"object","properties":{"name":{"type":"string"},"key":{"type":"string"},"html":{"type":"string"},"displayName":{"type":"string"},"avatarUrl":{"type":"string","format":"uri"}},"additionalProperties":false}},"total":{"type":"integer"},"header":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[An object containing list of matched user objects, with html representing highlighting.]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
2651,2655c2596
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a Response with the users matching the query]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="List of users"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>[{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=fred","key":"fred","accountId":"99:27935d01-92a7-4687-8272-a9b8d3b2ae2e","name":"fred","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&amp;ownerId=fred","24x24":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;ownerId=fred","16x16":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&amp;ownerId=fred","32x32":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&amp;ownerId=fred"},"displayName":"Fred F. User","active":false},{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=andrew","key":"andrew","accountId":"99:e2a16dd9-2ffb-4a4b-a9bd-bd1145a020ee","name":"andrew","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&amp;ownerId=andrew","24x24":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;ownerId=andrew","16x16":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&amp;ownerId=andrew","32x32":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&amp;ownerId=andrew"},"displayName":"Andrew Anderson","active":false}]</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returns a full representation of a JIRA user in JSON format.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/list-of-user#","title":"List of User","type":"array","items":{"title":"User","type":"object","properties":{"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"},"key":{"type":"string"},"accountId":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"emailAddress":{"type":"string"},"avatarUrls":{"type":"object","patternProperties":{".+":{"type":"string","format":"uri"}},"additionalProperties":false},"displayName":{"type":"string"},"active":{"type":"boolean"},"timeZone":{"type":"string"},"locale":{"type":"string"},"groups":{"$ref":"#/definitions/simple-list-wrapper"},"applicationRoles":{"$ref":"#/definitions/simple-list-wrapper"},"expand":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["active"]},"definitions":{"simple-list-wrapper":{"title":"Simple List Wrapper","type":"object","properties":{"size":{"type":"integer"},"max-results":{"type":"integer"},"items":{"type":"array","items":{"title":"Group","type":"object","properties":{"name":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"}},"additionalProperties":false}}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["size"]}}}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a Response with the users matching the query]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
2683,2687c2624
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a Response with the users matching the query]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="List of users"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>[{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=fred","key":"fred","accountId":"99:27935d01-92a7-4687-8272-a9b8d3b2ae2e","name":"fred","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&amp;ownerId=fred","24x24":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;ownerId=fred","16x16":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&amp;ownerId=fred","32x32":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&amp;ownerId=fred"},"displayName":"Fred F. User","active":false},{"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=andrew","key":"andrew","accountId":"99:e2a16dd9-2ffb-4a4b-a9bd-bd1145a020ee","name":"andrew","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&amp;ownerId=andrew","24x24":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;ownerId=andrew","16x16":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&amp;ownerId=andrew","32x32":"http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&amp;ownerId=andrew"},"displayName":"Andrew Anderson","active":false}]</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returns a full representation of a JIRA user in JSON format.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/list-of-user#","title":"List of User","type":"array","items":{"title":"User","type":"object","properties":{"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"},"key":{"type":"string"},"accountId":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"emailAddress":{"type":"string"},"avatarUrls":{"type":"object","patternProperties":{".+":{"type":"string","format":"uri"}},"additionalProperties":false},"displayName":{"type":"string"},"active":{"type":"boolean"},"timeZone":{"type":"string"},"locale":{"type":"string"},"groups":{"$ref":"#/definitions/simple-list-wrapper"},"applicationRoles":{"$ref":"#/definitions/simple-list-wrapper"},"expand":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["active"]},"definitions":{"simple-list-wrapper":{"title":"Simple List Wrapper","type":"object","properties":{"size":{"type":"integer"},"max-results":{"type":"integer"},"items":{"type":"array","items":{"title":"Group","type":"object","properties":{"name":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string","format":"uri"}},"additionalProperties":false}}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["size"]}}}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a Response with the users matching the query]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
3724,3728c3661
<                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a RemoteIssueLinkCreateOrUpdateResponse]]></ns2:doc><ns2:representation
<                             element="remote issue link"
<                                     mediaType="application/json"><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                                     xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Example</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":10000,"self":"http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/issue/MKY-1/remotelink/10000"}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><![CDATA[Returns a link to the created/updated remote issue link.]]></ns2:doc><ns2:doc><ns3:p
<                         xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ns3:h6>Schema</ns3:h6><ns3:pre><ns3:code>{"id":"https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/schema/remote-issue-link-create-or-update-response#","title":"Remote Issue Link Create Or Update Response","type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"},"self":{"type":"string"}},"additionalProperties":false}</ns3:code></ns3:pre></ns3:p></ns2:doc></ns2:representation></ns2:response><ns2:response
---
>                             status="200"><ns2:doc><![CDATA[a RemoteIssueLinkCreateOrUpdateResponse]]></ns2:doc></ns2:response><ns2:response
```

I hope this is of help...

Patrick